# Excel marco doesn't work after microsoft update today

Tags: excel, debugging, vba

After updating Microsoft to Version 16.9 this morning, I am now receiving errors.

All my macros are giving me this error:

> Run-time error '438'
>   Object doesn't support this property or method

Upon pressing Debug, the following line has been highlighted:

```
.UseListObject = False
```

Any idea what can be causing this?

Comment: Hi K.Dᴀᴠɪs, thanks for re-editing my typing.

Answer (score 0):

Are you should change `.UseListObject = False`
to 
`yourWbookX.Worksheets(1).UseListObject = False`

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi, Alg_D I tried to replace your code, but got same error, after I delete this line, the marco is working, but the find/replace function applies to entire workbook which that is not my expect.